# Websocket not working when internet connection restart

Tags: java, android, websocket, java-websocket

I am an android developer. I am using TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client library for websocket client.

It is working nice. But when I restart internet connection or connecting to wifi it is not working.  For working again I restart application.

I tried to reconnect or recreate but nothing helps.

App.java

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static WebSocket ws = null;
    WebSocketFactory factory = new WebSocketFactory().setConnectionTimeout(5000);

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        try {
            ws = factory.createSocket("wss://websocket/");
            ws.connectAsynchronously();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }
    public WebSocket getSocket(){
        try {
            if(!ws.isOpen())
            ws = ws.recreate();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
        return ws;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
....
            app.getSocket().addListener(getMessage);
String message;
        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("class", "userIdFromUser");
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
            data.put("message", userInfoSharedP.getUserId());
            data.put("senderId", userInfoSharedP.getUserId());

            json.put("data",data);
            message = json.toString();
            app.getSocket().sendText(message);
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at part Reconnection [here](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client).
You probably should use this:
`ws = ws.recreate().connect();`